# `<top (required)>': undefined method `“raf_ebooks' for main:Object (NoMethodError) -

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, nomethoderror

When trying to run my twitter_ebooks bot using `ruby run.rb` I get this error:

```
Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder.
/Users/Rafi/Desktop/my_ebooks/bots.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `“raf_ebooks' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from run.rb:33:in `require_relative'
    from run.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

Here is the git repo, of the bot I'm using, if that helps: https://github.com/mispy/twitter_ebooks

Here is what is inside the `bots.rb` file (I have removed the auth tokens and consumer key etc for security): http://pastebin.com/gYqcMYhM

What does this error mean and how can I fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: I tried running it again after restarting got pretty much the same error except instead of `my_ebooks/bots.rb:14` it says `my_ebooks/bots.rb:13`

```
Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder.
/Users/Rafi/Desktop/my_ebooks/bots.rb:13:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `“raf_ebooks”' for main:Object (NameError)
    from run.rb:33:in `require_relative'
    from run.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: @Substantial Im just using TextEdit, the default text editor for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have curly quotation marks that Ruby doesn't pick up. This happens when you use [word processors](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2523) that try to get fancy.

```
TWITTER_USERNAME = “raf_ebooks" # Ebooks account username
TEXT_MODEL_NAME = “raf_ebooks" # This should be the name of the text model
```

Notice the broken syntax highlighting. They should be "normal" straight quotes:

```
TWITTER_USERNAME = "raf_ebooks" # Ebooks account username
TEXT_MODEL_NAME = "raf_ebooks" # This should be the name of the text model
```

Much better.

Get yourself a decent editor. TextEdit is not suitable for coding. TextMate and Sublime Text are popular commercial editors. GitHub's [Atom](https://atom.io/) is a free editor, pretty nice too.

Answer (score 0):

The opening quote of the `TWITTER_USERNAME` value isn't a "regular" quote, it's some sort of smart quote.  Hence Ruby isn't recognising it as a string, and is getting rather confused.